# a chrome bug in css3 rotateX in :before

Tags: css, google-chrome

I found an useful transition in [this website](http://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeLinkEffects/#cl-effect-2)

`windows 7`, `chrome 31.0.1650.57 m` is well! but in:

`window XP`, `chrome 31.0.1650.57 m` or `chrome 21.0.1180.89` the weird animation happend

this is the mostly code

```
.cl-effect-2 a span {
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
-moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s;
transition: transform 0.3s;
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
-moz-transform-origin: 50% 0;
transform-origin: 50% 0;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.cl-effect-2 a span::before {
-webkit-transition: background 0.3s;
-moz-transition: background 0.3s;
transition: background 0.3s;
-webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
-moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
transform: rotateX(-90deg);
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
-moz-transform-origin: 50% 0;
transform-origin: 50% 0;
}

.cl-effect-2 a:hover span,
.cl-effect-2 a:focus span {
-webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-22px);
-moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-22px);
transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-22px);
}
```

Is this a bug in chrome? or how can i fixed it! thx!!!

Comment: Huh, I don't see any `::before` or `::after` element in those `<span>`s in XP Chrome 31 inspector. Firefox works great though.

Comment: Firefox works well, but in XP Chrome 31. the `span::before` disappeared when mouseover.

Comment: I found a `.csstransforms3d` before `.cl-effect-2 a span::before`, which seems be causing the problem. Remove the `.csstransforms3d` from that rule and XP Chrome 31 recognize the pseudo element.